# Jmeter Regex to match contents after newline

Tags: xpath, jmeter, newline

I have to write a regular expression to match child price i.e "18.99", since there are multiple span class with same class name i.e "currency & price-value", I wanted to write regex from CHILD, again here 4-11 is dynamic data, it can change.

`<p class="price">CHILD 4-11yrs<br />
   <span class="currency">&pound;</span>
   <span class="price-value">18.99</span></p>`

Wanted a regex which identifies from CHILD to fetch the price.
Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want to check if the `span` tag you need to get the value of contains a literal substring `CHILD`, you may as well use an [XPath_Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) and the following XPath query:

```
//span[parent::p[contains(text(),'CHILD')] and @class='price-value']/text()
```

**Details**:

- `//span` - get me a `span` tag...
- `[parent::p[contains(text(),'CHILD')]` - whose parent tag is `p` and whose value contains `CHILD` substring
- `and`  - *AND*...
- `@class='price-value']` - the `class` attribute value is `price-value`...
- `/text()`  - and fetch me the value of that `span`.

**NOTE**: If the `p` tag *starts with* the `CHILD`, you may as well use `starts-with`:

```
//span[parent::p[starts-with(text(),'CHILD')] and @class='price-value']/text()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Thank you. Is it possible to extract the same by using Regular Expression Extractor. ?

Comment: Yes, but do you really want to use such an incomprehensible [`<p\s[^<]*?\bclass="price"[^<]*?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/p>)[^<]*)*<span\s[^<]*?\bclass="price-value">([^<]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/zH6vT2/1)?

Comment: XPath is the only valid way to proceed. Trying to parse HTML with regex [only causes headache](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, CSS / JQuery is the correct way of extracting data from HTML. XPath is slow and prefered for XML content

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK: How slow is it? If we are talking about microseconds, then it is not that important, right? Also, can you make sure with the selectors that you get the correct `span.price-value`, not the arbitrary one? There are some restrictions as you can see.

Comment: you can do with css/jquery what you can do with xpath. Xpath is slow in terms of ms not micro.

Answer (score 0):

To extract HTML content, it is much better and easier to use [CSS/ JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor).

To extract what you need expression will be:

> span.price-value

Leave attribute empty and that's it